# <newbie> Objective C, saving a file in iPad apps

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I am creating a sample application where it downloads 100 images from 
server and stores it in iPad.

In XCode, I am using the `NSURL` to retrieve the image file and using 
`NSData` to save it into my local folder. 
I am able to save the images in my mac air desktop folder. But I want 
my application to be deployed in iPad. 
So here is my question:

- Where do I store the file in my iPad, so that my application can 
  retrieve the images when needed?
- If possible can someone give me the code for saving the images in 
  your iPad resource directory (or whatever directory needed). Just the 
  code where you build the path will do good.

I know this is kind of a basic question, since I am new to objective-C, I am kind of struggling with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example function how to retrieve the applications documents folder. In there you can create your own folder structure. This folder is also backed up by iTunes and will be preserved when doing application updates.

```
NSString* GetApplicationDocumentsDirectory() {
    static NSString* documentsDirectory = nil;
    if (documentsDirectory == nil) {
    documentsDirectory = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                               NSUserDomainMask,
                                                               YES)
                          objectAtIndex:0] retain];
    }
    return documentsDirectory;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion, using a Core Data store would be the best approach for this.